# Position spots on a 3D dice/die

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a 3D die using CSS3. I've built my cube, am able to rotate it around its Y and X axis,  and am capable of adding the spots on both the front and back, but I am struggling to position the die's spots on the left, right, top, and bottom accurately. I am a little new using transform properties so I'm sure this isn't as difficult as I'm making it.

Here are my code snippets. I have commented out the spots contained on the top, left, and bottom as I am strictly working to get the right side spots in position at the moment. Thanks for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.roll', function(){
    console.log("should be flipping")
    $('#cube').toggleClass("rolling")
  })
})
```

```css
.container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
#cube{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: 30px;

}
#cube figure{
  margin: 0;
  width: 196px;
  height: 196px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
figure{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.spot{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#front-1{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#front-2{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#front-3{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#front-4{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#front-5{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  margin-left: 140px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#front-6{
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  margin-left: 140px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#back-1{
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -25px;
}
.roll{
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #0000CD;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
.roll p{
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.front {
  transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px)
}
#cube .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px)
}
#cube .right{
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px)
}
#cube .left  {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px)
}
#cube .top   {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px)
}
#cube .bottom{
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px)
}
.rolling{
  transform:    rotateY( 90deg )
}
#cube {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="cube">
      <figure class="front"></figure>
        <div class="spot" id="front-1"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="front-2"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="front-3"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="front-4"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="front-5"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="front-6"></div>
      <figure class="back"></figure>
        <div class="spot" id="back-1"></div>
      <figure class="right"></figure>
        <div class="spot" id="right-1"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="right-2"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="right-3"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="right-4"></div>
        <div class="spot" id="right-5"></div>
      <figure class="left"></figure>
<!--         <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div> -->
      <figure class="top"></figure>
<!--         <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div> -->
      <figure class="bottom"></figure>
 <!--        <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div>
        <div class="spot"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="roll">
    <p>Roll the Dice</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only six div to create tha faces

Then use background-image to create the dots

See how to do it with the 3 face

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.three {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 64px 64px, white 40px, transparent 40px),
      radial-gradient(circle at 150px 150px, white 40px, transparent 40px),
      radial-gradient(circle at 236px 236px, white 40px, transparent 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="three"></div>
```